# OpenSSH's SSH client not respecting order of IdentityFile settings

Tags: openssh

How can I specify the order in which OpenSSH's SSH client (OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017; Git for Windows v2.11.1) offers the public/private key pairs to a SSH compliant daemon such as Apache Mina SSHD (Gerrit Code Review service). My intention is to try to authenticate with an Ed25519 public/private key pair before falling back to RSA.

Given the following standard Ed25519 and RSA public/private key pairs below the user's home directory:

- `~/.ssh/id_ed25519{,.pub}`
- `~/.ssh/id_rsa{,.pub}`

and the following Host sections in the user's SSH configuration file (~/.ssh/config):

```
Host foobar foobar.example.com
  Hostname foobar.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

when testing the SSH connection in debug mode:

```
$ ssh -Tv bob@foobar
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug1: ~/.ssh/config line 49: Applying options for foobar
debug1: ~/.ssh/config line 63: Applying options for *
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering ED25519 public key: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-ed25519 blen 51
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

I can see that OpenSSH's SSH client offers the RSA public/private key pair first. But why not first Ed25519?

Comment: Are both keys held by an SSH agent?

Comment: The reason I ask about the SSH agent is that OpenSSH offers keys from the agent _first_.

Comment: Yes, both keys are automatically added to a SSH agent after one was started during initialization of a Bash shell by one of its startup files.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the following exhaustive explanation: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/SSHIdentitiesOffered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `IdentitiesOnly` option. Without this option SSH tries first default ssh-keys available: `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa`. To change this behaviour replace your config with this one:

```
Host foobar foobar.example.com
  Hostname foobar.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Isn't the one `IdentitiesOnly yes`setting in the fallback section (`Host *`) enough for it to become effective in more host-specific sections?

Comment: @TimFriske You have put this option to every Host section with `IdentityFile` defined.